# Why is my <select> element's value is not present on the server?

Tags: php

Would it be legal to do something like this in order to get the user's selection from the drop-down list?

I know that I can use the `$_REQUEST['name']` when it's `<input type="text">` but I am not sure  if the request array saves the `<select>` value  as well as I am not getting the correct output.

The output should be: the name of the selected item. For example if I selected "drink coffee" It should print "drink coffee".

```
<?php
  $toDo=$_REQUEST['do today'];
  echo $toDo;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>

    <form action="planner.php" method="post">
       what would you like to do today?
       <select name="do today">
          <option value="drink coffee" >drink coffee</option>
          <option value="read book"  selected="selected">READ BOOK</option>
          <option value="take a walk">take a walk</option>
          <option value="buy a bagel">buy a bagel</option>
       </select>

     <br/>
     to submit your choices, press this button 
    <input type="submit" value="submit choice">

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand exactly what you are asking here. Would it be possible to give a little more explanations? Perhaps with some examples?

Comment: All these spaces everywhere scare me. Its generally good practice to keep variable names and ids without spaces.

Comment: change it `do today` for `dotoday`

Comment: I was going to say that....in your select name use do_today

Comment: I just realized that my php code wasn't added.. why is that ?

Comment: @Shiran - The code wasn't displayed because you need to leave a blank line between normal text and code blocks. Selecting the code and hitting `CTRL+K` will convert the text to code and also add the blank lines I was talking about. I've fixed it for you and also made some other improvements. Please let me know if you object to any of the changes I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use spaces in tag name.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form action="planner.php" method="post">
       what would you like to do today?
       <select name="do_today">
          <option value="drink coffee" >drink coffee</option>
          <option value="read book"  selected="selected">READ BOOK</option>
          <option value="take a walk">take a walk</option>
          <option value="buy a bagel">buy a bagel</option>
       </select>

     <br/>
     to submit your choices, press this button 
    <input type="submit" value="submit choice">

  </form>
 </body>
```

in planner.php get value by:

```
echo $_REQUEST['do_today'];
```

it will give you the value of selected option not the name of the option.  if you select   `<option value="read book"  selected="selected">READ BOOK</option>`

then it will give you `read book` not `READ BOOK`

It should make sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Well ... if you just want the value, its pretty easy:

```
$var = $_POST['dotoday'];
```

i would always recommend no spaces in names. Just annoys.

Im pretty sure i misunderstood you, because i always misunderstand people. So ask if something isnt clear or if my answer wasnt fully answering your question.

Comment: You understood very well. it's working.. I wasn't sure if I can obtain the drop-down list value..but I can. it was a syntax mistake.

Comment: Well, indeed, its possible to obtain the value of the dropdown menu, its treated like a textbox if you press the submit button, the current value will be sent and saved into the supervariable $_POST. Glad that i was able to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should `print_r` `$_POST` and see what field names `$_POST` contains.

On my computer, `$_POST` holds

```
Array ( [do_today] => buy a bagel )
```

eg the `<select>` name `do today` is interpredted as `do_today`

so I'll suggest

```
echo $_POST['do_today'];
```